# SequelizeUniqueConstraintError during seed

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a node.js application that uses Sequelize. I'm currently targeting SQLite for easy dev setup and testing but will be moving to MySQL for production. I used the sequelize-cli to create the models and migrations and all worked without any issues, I have confirmed that the tables were created using a SQLite browser tool. The problem I have now is when running the seed file that I have below (The database is currently empty) I receive the following error.

Error:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeUniqueConstraintError: Validation error
at Query.formatError (/Users/abc/repos/myProject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:231:14)
at Statement.<anonymous> (/Users/abc/repos/myProject/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/query.js:47:29)
at Statement.replacement (/Users/abc/repos/myProject/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/trace.js:20:31)
```

The migration:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Questions', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      text: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      nextQuestionId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Questions');
  }
};
```

The model:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    type: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    text: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nextQuestionId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Question.belongsTo(Question, {as: 'nextQuestion', foreignKey: 'nextQuestionId'});
        Question.hasMany(models.Answer);
        Question.hasMany(models.questionoption, {as: 'options'});
      }
    }
  });
  return Question;
};
```

The seed:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Questions', [
      {type: 0, text: 'Question A'},
      {type: 5, text: 'Question B', nextQuestionId: 4},
      {type: 5, text: 'Question C', nextQuestionId: 4},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question D'},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question E'},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question F'},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question G'},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question H'},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question I'}
    ], {});
  } ...
```

I have tried looking though the documentation and googling for answers, nothing seems to hint at this being a common problem. I didn't define any unique columns (other than the primary key of course, but it's an autoIncrement) If I had more information or clues as to which column was causing the issue from the cli then I would at least be able to try some different things, but no help there. I've tried running the equivalent inserts manually in SQL and they work, so I don't think it's the DB rejecting the insert, it appears to be something internal to Sequelize.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying a few options for a few days now with no luck.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The error appears to be extremely misleading. The solution, whether the correct one or not I'm not sure, but adding the createdAt and updatedAt attributes to the objects allowed them to seed successfully. My assumption was that these would be taken care of automatically by the ORM. The seed that worked looks like this (no changes to any models or migrations).

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert('Questions', [
      {type: 0, text: 'Question A', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 5, text: 'Question B', nextQuestionId: 4, createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 5, text: 'Question C', nextQuestionId: 4, createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question D', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question E', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question F', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question G', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question H', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()},
      {type: 0, text: 'Question I', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()}
    ], {});
  }, ...
```

Comment: Very misleading error, and your solution helped me solve it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
I added missing `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns but error still presist.
I was missing `;` at the end of the `bulkInsert` function.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `timeStamps:true` to your model and you're all good

```
module.exports = {
   ......
   .......
   updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE
  }
}, {
  timeStamps: true  // -> Add this
 }
}
```

Comment: It is true by default.